# How can I microbenchmark::microbenchmark the same function with different arguments programmatically?

Tags: r, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I have an unbounded named list of arguments for a function that I plan to use positionally, e.g.

```
list(
   method1 = "method1",
   method2 = "method2",
   ...,
   methodn = "methodn"
)
```

with

```
function(method) {
   if (identical(method, "method1")) {Sys.sleep(1); return(NULL)}
   if (identical(method, "method2")) {Sys.sleep(2); return(NULL)}
   Sys.sleep(nchar(method))
   return(NULL)
}
```

How can I use package:microbenchmark to benchmark my given function using the provided arguments?  Bonus points if the benchmark itself is named as the positional argument is named in my source list.

The prime for package:microbenchmark use I've seen scattered about is where the tasks to be benchmarked are specified in dots.  The argument `list` is available for evaluating unevaluated expressions; and that seems like the correct route for programmatic use.  However, because expression() treats the inside of the parens as literal, I haven't found a way to inject my argument inside of expression().  I walked down a dark road with parse(), and got it working - but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use cat and sprintf with a for loop, although it might become problematic if you have many combination  of parameters.

```
cat("res <- microbenchmark(\n")
for (i in 1:4){
  for (j in 1:4) {
    cat(sprintf("f_%i_%i = f(%i, %i),\n", i, j, i, j))
  }
}
cat(")\n")
```

Then copy-paste and run the code (remove the comma from the penultimate line).